# Why is 'throttle:api' registered differently than other middleware in Laravel?

Tags: laravel

In Laravel's `app\Http\Kernel.php` file the `'throttle:api'` middleware is registered as a string unlike all the other middleware. Why is that so? And what class does it reference?

```php
protected $middlewareGroups = [
        'web' => [
            \App\Http\Middleware\EncryptCookies::class,
            \Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\AddQueuedCookiesToResponse::class,
            \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class,
            // \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\AuthenticateSession::class,
            \Illuminate\View\Middleware\ShareErrorsFromSession::class,
            \App\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken::class,
            \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings::class,
        ],

        'api' => [
            'throttle:api',
            \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings::class,
        ],
    ];
```

Comment: because it is named for convenience as it is a route middleware (`throttle`) that you might add to other routes outside that group ... the other middleware are basically only used in the groups they are in and don't need a 'name'/'alias' ... **also** the `throttle` middleware is taking a parameter (`api`), that makes a difference